# My addEventListener('change', function(e){}); is not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am pretty new to javascript. Im trying to upload my image file but somehow I can only browse my file and my image is not uploading. I had a problem with `inputField.addEventListener('change', function(e){});`

I can see that my `addEventListener('click', () => {})` is working fine but I dont understand if I did `inputField.click();` it did not get into the `inputField.addEventListener('change', function(e){});`

```js
const draggerArea = document.getElementById('dragger');
const inputField = document.getElementById('fileInputField');
const dragText = document.getElementById('drag-text');
const fileName = document.getElementById('fileName');
const browseFile = document.getElementById('uploadFile');

browseFile.addEventListener('click', () => {
  inputField.value = ""
  alert(String("hello"))
  inputField.click();
});

inputField.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  file = this.files[0];
  alert(String(file))
  fileHandler(file);
});

const fileHandler = (file) => {
  alert("hello")
  const validExt = ["image/jpeg", "image/jpg", "image/png"]
  if (validExt.includes(file.type)) {

    const fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = () => {
      const fileURL = fileReader.result;
      let imgTag = `<img src=${fileURL} alt=""/>`
      draggerArea.innerHTML = imgTag;
      let paragraph = `<div class="fileName"><p>${file.name.split('.')[0]}</p><i class="fa-solid fa-trash-can" onclick={deleteHandler()}></i></div>`
      fileName.innerHTML = paragraph;
    }
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
    draggerArea.classList.add('active')
  } else {
    draggerArea.classList.remove('active');
    dragText.textContent = "Drag and Drop File"
  }
};
```

```html
<div id="dragger_wrapper">
  <div id="dragger">
    <div class="icon"><i class="fa-solid fa-images"></i></div>
    <h2 id="drag-text">Drag and Drop File</h2>
    <h3>Or</h3>
    <button class="uploadFile" id="uploadFile">Browse File</button>
    <input type="file" hidden id="fileInputField" />

  </div>
  <div id="fileName"> </div>
</div>

<script src="dragAndDropController.js"></script>
```

Comment: Are you seeing any console errors? I don't think you can modify the file input value because that would be quite insecure, which means it hasn't changed, but, I could be wrong

Comment: There's no console error at all.

Comment: Seems to work ok for me - clicking "browse file" does a (horrid) alert, prompts for file, then displays "[File object]" then another (horrid, blocking) alert - if it's an image, the image is displayed along with the filename  (debug with console.log, not alert also blocks which has been the cause of many questions on SO).   What's the actual problem?

Comment: PS, it's better to use `URL.createObjectURL(file)` instead of using the filereader.

Answer (score 0):

[modified code](https://jsfiddle.net/thanhtutzaw/absop9qe/5/)

you have no problem with `inputField.addEventListener('change', function(e){});`

[tutorial on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wtrin7C4b7w)
You want to to click hidden input and it is also working when you click browse button. This is not complete upload process . It is just displaying the file and need to store image in server.
Here is  [uploading with php](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JaRq73y5MJk)